# Prove a sequence does not converge

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Prove that the sequence with $n^{th}$ term $s_n=\frac{2}{n^2}$ does not converge to $-1$.

I'm trying to use contradiction to prove, like $\left|\dfrac{2}{n^2}+1\right|<1$, but I can't solve the inequality.

Any suggestion? Appreciate!

Comment: How could a sequence consisting of positive terms converge to a negative number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence converged to $-1$, you would have $|s_n+1| \to 0$. Since
$|s_n+1| = \frac{2}{n^2}+1 > 1$, it is not possible that $|s_n+1|\to 0$.